# data error in boot\grub ... file broken

Tags: boot, grub2, usb-creator

So I am trying to make my usb stick bootable and load ubuntu 14.04 64 bit on it.
I have tried different methods,
for example, I format my usb on windows to be FAT32 and then am using the Universal USB installer loading iso file into it. However, I am getting 192 errors ! which most of the look like Data error in boot\grub\x86_64-efi*.mod. File is broken.

I also have boot the usb stick in different format, but still no success. I appreciate any comment.

Comment: Did you check the MD5 checksum for the image?

Comment: the file was not healthy ! as you guessed

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: yes ! I downloaded another iso file

Answer (score 1):

the iso file I had was some how corrupted ... so I downloaded a new one and then it worked fine. thanks @Raphael